# Transformation of random variable, let $Z = X, W = Y^2$ find joint PDF

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Given random variables $X,Y$, I wish to find the joint PDF of $Z,W$, where $$Z = X, W = Y^2$$

We proceed using the classical procedure described here: https://turing.une.edu.au/~stat354/notes/node25.html

First, $z = x, w = y^2 \implies J(x,y) = \begin{vmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2y \end{vmatrix} = 2y$, where $J(x,y)$ is the Jacobian

Then $$f_{ZW}(z,w) = \frac{1}{|J(x,y)|}f_{XY}(x,y)|_{(z = x, w = y^2)}$$

Here is where I am having trouble with. Suppose that $w \geq 0$, then $y = \pm \sqrt{w}$

Thus $$f_{ZW}(z,w) = \frac{1}{|\pm2 \sqrt{w}|}f_{XY}(z,\pm \sqrt{w}) = \frac{1}{|2 w|}f_{XY}(z,\pm \sqrt{w})$$

Since we have an absolute value sign on the denominator, so the bottom plus minus sign goes away. **How can I simply the expression** $f_{XY}(z,\pm \sqrt{w})$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That $\pm$ y  that you don't know how to handle is telling you something important that you're missing. The method you're using doesn't really work as advertised when the transformation isn't one-to-one. We can see this with a simpler single-variable problem where we have a continuous RV $X$ with PDF $f_X(x)$ and want to get the distribution of $U=X^2.$

First off, like with your $W,$ it's clear that our $U$ is always non-negative, so its distribution only has support on the non-negative numbers. The method you used basically assumes that the distribution of $U$ at some point $u$ only "comes from" one corresponding point $x$ in the distribution of $X.$ But in this case, both $x=\sqrt{u}$ and $x=-\sqrt{u}$ map to the point $u$ under the function $x^2$ so the probability of $U$ being near $u$ will be related to both the probability of $X$ being near $x=\sqrt{u}$ and that of $X$ being near $x=-\sqrt{u}.$ Similar consideration about the transformation of the density occur at each point and we expect something like $$ f_U(u) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{u}} f_X(\sqrt{u}) + \frac{1}{2\sqrt u} f(-\sqrt{u}).$$ 
The point $u=0$ is special in that it only gets mapped to by one point, but for a continuous distribution we can disregard this since we know $P(U=0) = 0$ anyway.

To confirm this is true we can compute the cumulative $$ F_U(u) = P(U\le u) \\= P(X^2\le u) \\= P(-\sqrt u \le X \le \sqrt u) \\= P(X\le \sqrt u) -P(X \ge -\sqrt u) \\= F_X(\sqrt{u}) - (1-F_X(-\sqrt{u})).$$ To get the PDF, we differentiate, obtaining $$ f_U(u) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}F'_X(\sqrt{u}) + \frac{1}{2\sqrt{u}}F'_X(-\sqrt u)\\=f_U(u) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{u}} f_X(\sqrt{u}) + \frac{1}{2\sqrt u} f(-\sqrt{u}) $$ as expected.

This allows us to see the answer to your distribution right away: $$ f_{ZW}(z,w) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{w}} f_{XY}(z,\sqrt{w}) +\frac{1}{2\sqrt{w}} f_{XY}(z,-\sqrt{w}).$$

**Addendum**
I think you were just asking about simplification cause of the square root, but in case you were asking more generally, I should say that we can't simplify it any more than this. $f$ could be a pretty arbitrary function, so meaningful simplification can only be obtained when you have an explicit form you can plug into.